# How to use urllib2 in python 3.4 to get information from an API?

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude of the ISS from the site:

https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544

I have managed to work out I need to use urllib2, but I can't install it using pip, I get the error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib2 <from the version: > 
No matching distribution found for urllib2
```

Could someone tell me how I can install urllib2 and also the code I would need to use to get the latitude and longitude? Thanks.

Comment: urllib2 is bundled with Python 3.4, you don't need to install it. As far as the code, look at the docs.

Comment: Another alternative is Anaconda distribution. It contains most of the libraries and modules you would even need...

Answer (score 3):

Python3.4 includes `urllib` (not `urllib2`) by default. To use it, simply `import urllib`.

Also, be aware that you should follow `urllib` [docs for Python3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) because things have been moved and are in a different place from where you would expect them if you were looking at `urllib2`, which was for Python2.

For instance, to request a url using `urllib`, you would do the following:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen(url) as link:
    result = link.read()
```

However, it is recommended (even by the `urllib` documentation) that you use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead:

```
$ pip install requests
```

Then, to use requests, you can do the following:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get(url)
etc.
```

Finally, your endpoint up there is returning JSON, so using `requests` you can access those values in the following way:

```
>>> result = response.json()
>>> result['some_key']
['some values...']
```

Comment: I have tried using this method, but i get a huge error thrown when I input the line  "response = requests.get(url)" any ideas?

Comment: A `huge error` is not descriptive enough. The code I posted is very straightforward and should work unless you're getting an `SSLError`, which means you can't trust the security certificate of the site you're trying to access. You can pass `verify=False`, i.e., `requests.get(url, verify=False`) when making the request, but there are issues with blanket trusting all sites.

Comment: Yes it was an SSLError, but the urllib method worked fine after I switched back to that, thank you.